# What is this Behringer X1622USB footswitch insert used for?

Tags: mixer, input

The [Xenyx X1622USB](https://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Analog-Mixers/X1622USB/p/P0A0J#) has a FX Footswitch insert at the top of the board near the Behringer Logo.

Is this used with a regular footswitch to turn the effect "Off" or "On"?
Nothing in the [manual](http://www.kunstencentrumbelgie.com/overbelgie/BEHRINGER2442USB.pdf) provided.

Or is this where you connect a Guitar Effects Pedal into?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/behringer-xenyx-2442fx) SOS article, it is for a latching footswitch to bypass the FX section.

> A stereo TRS jack carries the output from the internal effects section and there's an effects bypass footswitch jack for use with an optional latching footswitch.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Behringer XENYX X1222 USB mixer, and I can confirm that you need TRS cable and footswitch to mute the effects. I used the TGI footswitch, model TGFS1. Works perfectly, allowing me to switch off effects during normal speech.